# SendGridAPIClient Not Found

Tags: c#, sendgrid-api-v3

In the following code, there is a compilation error

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'SendGridAPIClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) XYZ.Core.Dll    XYZ.Core.Dll\Fabric\AppConfiguration.cs 87  Active

I'm not sure what library I'm missing

```
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;

private static SendGridAPIClient _SendGridApiClient;
```

this is what I have in packages.config

```
<package id="Sendgrid" version="9.10.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SendGrid.Api" version="1.0.7" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SendGrid.CSharp.HTTP.Client" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SendGrid.SmtpApi" version="1.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SendGridClient" version="2.0.0-preview2" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: If I had to guess, a `SendGrid` library. Is your project missing a NuGet package?

Comment: Thank you for your replay @DanielMann, I added my packages.config content related to SendGrid to description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the steps described in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/
this will make sure you have referenced the send grid dll.

Comment: PM> Install-Package Sendgrid -Version 9.10.0
Package 'Sendgrid.9.10.0' already exists in project 'Gnowise.Core.Dll'

Comment: Uninstall it and re-install it will resolve the issue. You can also manually refer the dll from your `package` folder